# Oracle SQL how to write a sql statement that verifies if user in my network( ie friends or friend of friends)

Tags: sql, oracle, social-networking

I have this problem.  Given a `users` table that consists of users' username in a social network and `friends` table that contain a user's name and a user's friendname like below...

```
username friendname

John        Thomas
Chris       James
```

... I'm trying to write an SQL statement that will if a user is in my network.  In other words
is that user a friend or friend of friends?

I've been dancing around this problem and could only come up with this query:

```
SELECT f2.username, f2.friendname 
FROM friends f2 
WHERE f2.username IN (
      SELECT f1.friendname 
      FROM friends f1 
      WHERE f1.username = 'Thomas') 
AND f2.friendname <> 'user1' 
AND f2.friendname = 'user2';
```

It basically check if a user if is a friend of my friend i.e. just return null if false.

Trying to figure out how I can expand to go through all my network of friend. I mean not just friend of my friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  username
        FROM    friends
        START WITH
                username = 'myname'
        CONNECT BY
                friendname = PRIOR username
                AND level <= 3
        )
WHERE   username = 'friendname'
        AND rownum = 1
```

Update the level as necessary: you may search for the third layer friends etc.

If the friendship relationship is symmetric, you should make the following query:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  username, friendname
        FROM    friends
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  friendname, username
        FROM    friends
        ),
        f AS
        (
        SELECT  friendname, level
        FROM    q
        START WITH
                username = 'Thomas'
        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                username = PRIOR friendname
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    f
WHERE   friendname = 'Jo'
        AND rownum = 1
```

This query can be made much faster if you denormalize your table: store two records per friendship, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dual_friends (orestes NOT NULL, pylades NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_dualfriends_op PRIMARY KEY (orestes, pylades)) ORGANIZATION INDEX
AS
SELECT  username, friendname
FROM    friends
UNION ALL
SELECT  friendname, username
        FROM    friends
```

Then you can just replace the `CTE` above with the `dual_friends`:

```
WITH    f AS
        (
        SELECT  pylades, level
        FROM    dual_friends
        START WITH
                orestes  = 'Thomas'
        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                orestes = PRIOR pylades
                AND level <= 3
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    f
WHERE   pylades = 'Jo'
        AND rownum = 1
```

, which will use the index and be much more efficient, especially if you limit the level to some reasonable value.

Comment: However oracle has Hierarchial queries using connect by so will do the level searching for you

Comment: That sql does seem to work for me. ok, imagine given this table
username  friendname
Thomas     Alice
Alice      Bob
Bob        Jo
Running that sql with myname = Thomas and friendname='Jo' give nothing indicating Jo is not in Thomas network, which is incorrect

Comment: @user: Is your friendship relationship symmetric? That is, if `Alice` is `Thomas`'s friend, is `Thomas` the `Alice`'s friend as well? I believe he is, but it is better to specify it.

Comment: @Quassnoi, do u want to try your query on this sample table
username friendname                                                          Thomas     Alice
Alice      Bob
Bob        Jo

it seems to be returning nothing, not sure if it is me

Comment: @Quassnoi,I actually managed to get it working using some of your previous suggestions and tweaking plus googling. But this new one beats it though, looks like i still ve a lot to learn. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`connect by`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-may/o35asktom.html)